# How do I redirect only URLs 4 folder levels deep but not 3 levels

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site needs to redirect everything with four subfolders to a different subdomain...

```
domain.com/1/2/3/4
```

must not redirect

and

```
domain.com/1/2/3
```

must redirect to

```
newsub.domain.com/1/2/3
```

Comment: Please clarify. Your title says "redirect 4-deep but not 3-deep" and the example says "redirect 3-deep but not 4-deep".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect `domain.com/1/2/3/4` but not `domain.com/1/2/3` use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://sub.domain.com/$1/$2/$3/$4 [L]
```

If you want to redirect `domain.com/1/2/3` but not `domain.com/1/2/3/4` this should help you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://sub.domain.com/$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

Comment: Side note: You could use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `/$1/$2/$3` -- the result will be the same since path part of URL remains the same and only domain name changes.